# Orbeon Concatenate Number and % symbol

Tags: xpath, orbeon

Following is the requirement, Input box should
 1. Accept only Numbers 
 2. Once User enters Number it should concatenate '%' in same control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this like this

1. Took normal Input
2. Replaced %
3. Checked whether its number

It works fine for me.

Here is the complete code

```
 matches(replace($ControlName,'%',''), '^[0-9_]+$')
```

Don't forget put his code under validation.